# how to save user's information(login web service) or create a session's user in xamarin.forms

Tags: session, cookies, xamarin.forms

i can't find the right direction, i am trying to retrieve user's token that is saved in cookies when logging in, i am using xamarin.forms and consuming web services with httpclient , i am not using web view, i posted a question here :
[My detailed question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93286/get-cookie-from-httpclient-request/p1?new=1)

i used cookiecontainer but it retrieves 0 cookie, is there any thing to create sessions, or save users information, i am really lost 
what should i do! 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

checkout the setting plugin by james here [github.com - jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin)

On Login page save your authentication token in local storage using settings plugin, then  in your `app.cs` check for the auth token if exist navigate to your dashboard or navigate to login page.

Hope this answers your question, let me know in comment if there is any problem in this approach.

Comment: Thanks, i am trying to apply it, how to assign an element of http response after deserializing it , to the setting's value!

Comment: the plugin's Readme explains pretty much everything right from its usage.

Comment: yes i have applied it, with strings no problem, but with int am getting this :
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93509/plugins-settings-error#latest

Comment: check in your android and iOS project `Helpers/settings.cs` and change the data type for your key from `string` to `int`

Comment: i am testing it with windows platform, not android or IOS, 
the problem came from here: 
 get { return Settings.Id; }